# Use foldl to traverse a Tree in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tree

I've got the following code:

```
data Tree a = ATree a [Tree a] 
            deriving Show

treeFold :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
treeFold f acc (ATree a [])      = f acc a 
treeFold f acc (ATree a m)       = foldl (treeFold f acc) (f acc a) m
```

It's supposed to go over each element of Tree and apply a function to the value. But it gives me this error:

```
Couldn't match type `Tree a' with `Tree a -> b'
    Expected type: (Tree a -> b) -> a -> Tree a -> b
      Actual type: b -> a -> b
    In the first argument of `treeFold', namely `f'
    In the first argument of `foldl', namely `(treeFold f acc)'
    In the expression: foldl (treeFold f acc) (f acc a) m
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first input to `foldl` you have has type `Tree a -> b` but it should actually have type `b -> Tree a -> b`. Just get rid of the acc in the first argument.

```
treeFold f acc (ATree a m) = foldl (treeFold f) (f acc a) m
```

Comment: Thanks very much indeed. I was banging my head for quite a while.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the error description? I don't get the problem.

Comment: Sure, but I don't really know what your confusion is, so I don't know what to tell you besides what I have written. Care to elaborate what you don't understand?

Answer (score 3):

First off, please don't use `foldl`. It's almost always bad and it's strict cousin `foldl'` is a much better behaved and properly tail-recursive function.

In any case, `foldl` expects to supply it's function with the accumulator which you're already doing by applying `treeFold` to `acc`, instead just use `foldl' (treeFold f)`.